# Making listview arraylist on the next line and changing listview text color

Tags: java, android, firebase, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database

How to make is so that the array list will show in the next line?

example: Instead of Member Name: lalala / Member Until: Random date It would become

- Member Name: lalala
- Member Until: Random date

And also, how can I change the text color of the listview on my array?

Anyway here is my code

```
public class memberFragment extends Fragment {
private ListView mylistView;
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
ArrayList<String> myArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
FirebaseDatabase myFirebase;


public memberFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_member2, container, false);

    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("Accounts").child("Users");
    ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                String date = ds.child("date").getValue(String.class);
                myArrayList.add("Member Name: "+name + " / " + "Member Until :"+date);
                Log.d("TAG", name + " / " + date);
            }
            final ArrayAdapter<String> myArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,myArrayList);
            mylistView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView);

            mylistView.setAdapter(myArrayAdapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    };
    usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);



    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return view;



}
```

And my .xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.google.firebase.ikuzou.database.memberFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ListView.Menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    />
```

Comment: post your xml file for your adapter, and do you want to change the background of whole list or just a single item. ?

Comment: I want to change the text color of the whole list and thanks added the xml

Comment: No post the xml for adapter not of your listview :)

Comment: :O. I don't have an xml for the adapter. I'm using firebase to get the data

Comment: Then you can't customize it :). you will have to use custom adapter for that.
and also you can try using /n as a last resort in  myArrayList.add("Member Name: "+name + " / " + "Member Until :"+date);

Comment: Hello, Where should i put the /n?. And oh feels bad to hear that. So it isn't possible at all even if i just want to make the text color into white?

Comment: in between "+name + " / " + "Member Until :" but I believe you cannot do that either. And yes you cannot change it's color. This is because you are using android's default layout and adapter. If you want to customize you listview then use custom adapter with custom layout. and it's not that difficult either :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Split characters in next line you should use this :

```
myArrayList.add("Member Name: "+name + " \n " + "Member Until :"+date);
```

about second query you should make changes in itemview.xml(single row xml) file.